# Signature Pad Using C# Code Behind Will Not Allow Signature Insertion

Tags: c#, css, code-behind, signaturepad

@szimek I am trying to implement your Signature Pad in a C# Web Forms application. The signature pad displays and the Clear button is clickable, but the canvas won't open up to allow entry of the signature. I have had to change signature-pad ID to signaturepad, could that be the reason it isn't working? HELP!!

```html
</div>
    <hr class="double" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfimg" runat="server" />
       <div id="signaturepad" class="signature-pad" runat="server">
    <div class="signature-pad--body" runat="server">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="signature-pad--footer" runat="server">
      <div class="description">Sign above</div>

      <div class="signature-pad--actions" runat="server">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@4.0.0/dist/signature_pad.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Content/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had much trouble getting this to work, and then finally found another route to accomplish capturing a signature. https://supersignature.com/ does the job with only a $119 one-time commitment, and only a few lines of code.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `app.js`? At least the relevant parts. It sounds like you didn't instantiate the signature pad.